# Am I doing this right? If not could someone please explain how it's supposed to work?

Tags: ruby

Hello i would like to know what wrong with my code

```
 pizza = "2.99"

puts "hello what would you like to buy?"
food_type = gets.chomp.downcase

puts "How many?"
food_amount = gets.chomp!

puts #{food_amount.to_i * food_type.to_f}
```

Comment: I guess two things. If you use to_f in a String (what you're using to save what the user is going to buy), then you get `0.0`. You need double quotes to interpolate `puts "1 + 1 is #{1 + 1}"`. You need the product's price.

Comment: Hey uhm. Could you exlplain further?

Comment: What is `food_type.to_f` supposed to be?

Comment: its the variable thats gonna save what type of food

Comment: before this im using case

Comment: https://repl.it/@XxCoderGodxX/SuperMegaAwesomeUltraPizza

Comment: click that and hopefully it will make more sense

Comment: The last `puts` is not valid Ruby code. `#{...}` must occur *inside* quotes, not just on its own. If the code here can reproduce the problem we can help you. That link is a lot of code to go through.

Comment: well it does. I'm trying to figure out how to make it multiply the number given (food_amount) by the string said (food_type) the problem is, I don't know how to make it register "pizza" as the variable in earlier lines of code.

Comment: This is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do something like this, you should store the different types of food in hash, and with `{ "food type" => cost of food }` (for example, `{ 'pizza' => 9.99, 'soda' => 2.99, 'breadsticks' => 1.50 }`) Note the prices are already floats, so no conversion is needed later.

Then when you loop through, you can save what they buy in another hash `{ 'food type' => quantity }`, with the quantity being an integer. Then, when they finish selecting items, you loop through the 'cart' and multiply everything out:

```
menu = { 'pizza' => 9.99, 'soda' => 2.99, 'breadsticks' => 1.50 }
cart = Hash.new(0)

begin
  puts "hello what would you like to buy?"
  food_type = gets.chomp.downcase

  puts "How many?"
  quantity = gets.to_i

  cart[food_type] += quantity

  puts "Want Anything Else?"
  buy_more = (gets.chomp == "yes")
end while buy_more

puts "you're buying:"
cart.each do |food_type, quantity|
  puts "#{quantity} of #{food_type} for #{quantity * menu.fetch(food_type, 0)}"
end
```

Example Run:

```
hello what would you like to buy?
soda
How many?
2
Want Anything Else?
yes
hello what would you like to buy?
pizza
How many?
5
Want Anything Else?
yes
hello what would you like to buy?
breadsticks
How many?
1
Want Anything Else?
yes
hello what would you like to buy?
something else
How many?
10
Want Anything Else?
no
you're buying:
2 of soda for 5.98
5 of pizza for 49.95
1 of breadsticks for 1.5
10 of something else for 0
```

Read more about [`Hash` in the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html), which should have enough info to get you going on the parts of your repl that I haven't added and decide how you'd like to handle invalid entries (like when I entered 'something else' for a food type). This example just treats it as a valid item with no price.